# @font-face doesn't work online

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I've got a problem with fonts, exactly with "@font-face".
When i tried to run this local HTML page, all fonts worked, but now when i try to run online HTML page, only one font is working.

now i have two fonts, one work, and one other doesn't

CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RemachineScript';
    src: url(fonts/SCRIPTIN.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    src: url(fonts/Quicksand.otf);
}

header#subheader div.title {
    font-family: 'RemachineScript';
}

header#subheader p.subheader {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
}
```

You can see the HTML at http://gspinaci.com/

The URLs are right, because they are in the same folder. What can I do?

Comment: Can you confirm that the font file is actually there? When trying to access the font, I receive a 404. It is also possible that your web server is not equipped to serve OTF files, and you might need to add that extension/MIME type.

Comment: It doesn't appear http://gspinaci.com/assets/fonts/Quicksand.otf exists on your server.

Comment: Make sure your server is set to serve the correct MIME-types.

Comment: well, thanks.
Now i have to update the server, to include OTF extension file.

Comment: I'm never sure if the `src` is supposed to be relative to the CSS file or to the HTML page. So to be safe, I always use a `src` relative to the site root: `url(/assets/fonts/SCRIPTIN.ttf)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console says there is no Quicksand.otf file, be sure of two things, first, that the file is there and the name is exactly the same (case sensitive) and the second this is that your font-face call is very specific, use the webkit font that you can download from font squirrel here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand

and be sure to paste in you CSS file the WHOLE font-face call, like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'triplex';
 src: url('fonts/triplexsans-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/triplexsans-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/triplexsans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/triplexsans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/triplexsans-light-webfont.svg#triplexlight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And remember to include all font format files, not only .otf.

EDIT

You do not need to configure your server, you only need to modify your .htaccess file, add this lines to it:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/opentype otf
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

Answer (score 0):

check this answer: [@font-face issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586598/font-face-issue/)
What you have in accepted answer is not nearly close to bulletproof;)
you can also try out my little converter http://freedockstar.com/fontface/

also i'm not sure if you need to set mime types for fonts. It works just fine from my server without it. Every font is server as text/html and there are no problems. you define type in css, and that seams to be enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add:

> format (truetype)
>   or
>   format (opentype)
>   or someone else after src attribute

```
@font-face{
   font-family: 'RemachineScript';
   src: url(fonts/SCRIPTIN.ttf) format (truetype);
}
```

you can find format type in fonts ttf file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but for the record... I solved this issue by granting read permission on the .ttf file.

```
chmod +r font.ttf
```